# Text Alignment problem with Chinese character using TextFX

Tags: unicode, notepad++, sqlplus, text-alignment

I tried to align two string containing chinese and latin characters.

Using pipeline `|` or another character e.g. `;` with TextFX plugin could not align the columns properly. Here is the result, you can easily reproduce this issue from menu using:

TextFX > TextFX Edit > Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)

```
|示例段落|EXAMPLE1
|LATIN       |EXAMPLE2
```

I assume that the plugin calculate this operation as, the col(15) in the first row the second row- is equals to ending of chinese string the col(6). Due to some byte operations or half-width, full-width character related.

I want to align these strings as : **(The pipeline should show the same column number)** - How can i achieve this ?

```
|示例段落  |EXAMPLE1
|LATIN    | EXAMPLE2
```